# Newcomer's Rhyming Riddle IV - What Am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> A base for protest in December;
>   The sweater for a special member.
>   A kiss or stroke, with sport or game;
>   Before your eyes, a prophet's claim.
>   The road that splits before nineteen;
>   When stung, I am what once has been.
>   A valued rock, when minus one;
>   I cross a stream, with aid from sun.
>   A hint at future, free from light;
>   The cry for sphere that's out of sight.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You sound like

> Fore (or for).

A base for protest in December

> [Deforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deforce) - fore 'in' Dec - meaning to unlawfully withhold land or property from its true owner. If this occurred it would be grounds for protest. There is a documentary [Deforce](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1619638/) on the history of Detroit.
>
>   <sub>This is the best I can think of, other being [Forefathers' Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forefathers%27_Day) though not a strong explanation for the base for protest.</sub>

The sweater for a special member

> The sweater may be skin. Append this and use your imagination as to what the special member is.

A kiss or stroke, with sport or game

> Foreplay  - this is kiss/stroke.  Play (sport/game) is added to fore.

Before your eyes, a prophet's claim

> Foresight - a prophet's claim. Sight which is 'what is before your eyes' is added to fore.

The road that splits before nineteen

> Fork - using *For* and adding *K* which is the chemical symbol for Potassium atomic number 19.

When stung, I am what once has been

> Before - the prefix sounding like bee for a stinger.

A valued rock, when minus one

> Ore - a rock source of metals after subtracting one letter.

I cross a stream, with aid from sun

> Ford - a shallow river crossing.
>   *For* plus vitamin *D* which is manufactured in human skin cells with help from sunlight UVB rays.

A hint at future, free from light

> Foreshadow - add shadow which is free from light.

The cry for sphere that's out of sight

> Shouting  [fore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fore_(golf)) when a golf ball is hit as a warning.

Comment: Nice, I'll leave you and others to try to figure out the first line.

Comment: Tried to explain the first line - not too confident.

Comment: "Append this" ... for a certain *append*age?

Comment: Oops ... that was a Freudian slip.